# Sort Method for Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Trying to figure out how to sort my doubly linked list.
I get a null pointer exception here:

```
while (temp.getNext()!=null){
```

Is there a better approach or any advice to get this going the right way?

```
public void sort() {
    //bubble sort!
    boolean swapped = (head != null);
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;

        EntryNode temp = head;

        //can't swap something with nothing
        while (temp.getNext()!=null){
            if (temp.getLastName().compareTo(temp.getNext().getLastName()) > 0) {
                swapped = true;

                //special case for two nodes
                if (size == 2) {
                    //reassign head and tail
                    tail = temp;
                    head = temp.getNext();
                    tail.setPrev(head);
                    head.setNext(tail);
                    tail.setNext(null);
                    head.setNext(null);
                }
                //if swapping is at head
                else {

                    if (temp == head) {
                        head = temp.getNext();
                        temp.setNext(head.getNext());
                        head.getNext().setPrev(temp);
                        head.setPrev(null);
                        head.setNext(temp);
                        temp.setPrev(head);
                    }

                    else {
                        temp.setNext(temp.getNext().getNext());
                        temp.setPrev(temp.getNext());
                        temp.getNext().setNext(temp);
                        temp.getNext().setPrev(temp.getPrev());
                    }
                }
            }
            //loop through list
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has to be homework. You don't sort linked lists in the real world.

Comment: @EJP In LISP-based languages you sort linked lists all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm, is often the [best choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Comparison_with_other_sort_algorithms) for sorting a (single or doubly) linked list. There's already a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938495/sorting-a-doubly-linked-list-with-merge-sort) discussing the relevant implementation issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check for:

```
while(temp != null)
```

because you are already assigning

```
temp = temp.getNext()
```

at the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to put the list contents into an array, use `Arrays.sort` to sort the array, and finally rebuild the list from the sorted array.

Comment: This approach will need two traversals of the list, ideally you should sort the doubly linked list in one traversal or in O(nlg n)(when using recursion)

Comment: @ShankhoneerChakrovarty - This is not correct.  The OP is doing a bubble sort, and that requires N traversals of the list.  Adding 2 more traversals is not going to affect the complexity.  It is provably impossible to sort a list of arbitrary comparable objects  in better than `O(NlogN)` comparisons ... which roughly equates to `O(logN)` traversals.  Once again, adding a constant 2 more traversals doesn't change the complexity.  (The sorts that are better than `O(NlogN)` rely on special properties of the domain of values being sorted.)