# Is quicksort "friendly" to on-CPU caches?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, caching, memory-management, cpu

Presume array to be sorted is much bigger than the biggest on-CPU cache (like at least two orders of magnitude bigger).

Since quicksort involves moving values higher than pivot above pivot and vice 
versa, I imagine it's not very CPU-cache friendly at beginning stages of sorting?

At later stages (small sub-arrays) it might be cache friendly, but what about the cost at initial stages?

Has anybody calculated some formulas about cost of cache misses and cache hits and how it impacts overall cost of quicksort?

Comment: There have been a huge number of academic studied about cache effects and sorting, which are readily searchable. Here is just one, thaks to Google's feeling lucky button: http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/frederik/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is quicksort is related to cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444714/how-is-quicksort-is-related-to-cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical sort algorithms in high-performance languages will stop recursing not at one element as the theory suggests, but as 2^N elements (16 or so) to use a hardcoded sort for the last phase. This keeps the sorting within a cache line efficient.

In the initial phases, though, it doesn't really matter whether two elements are separated by 200 or 20000 elements. They're on distinct cache lines either way.

Comment: "They're on distinct cache lines either way." I understand that, but since each recursive partition touches every memory location over and over (say pivot in the middle of array, 1st partition, iterate over all keys; 2nd partition, 2 recursive calls again touch every memory location above and below pivot, etc), does that not have consequence of overwriting (LRU expunging?) the same cached value of a memory location over and over? If  particular quicksort requires N partitions and array is much bigger than cache, that means almost N re-fetches of every cached value.

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U: However, it does not leap about within the partition; it scans the partition linearly (usually forwards and backwards, but still linearly). Also, it takes exactly as many recursions to reach N/4 as to go from N/4 to N/16, but the second set of recursions (and all following ones) are entirely within the N/4 partition. So it's not really "almost N".