# Arrays.sort() -- two different strategies for primitive & complex data types to be sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures

[`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is sorting the primitive data types using the method `DualPivotQuicksort`, 
and the complex types separately-- using merge-sort. (insertion-sort if the input size is small).

`DualPivotQuicksort` is using merge-sort still on large input sizes, however, it is using dual-quicksort on a range of smaller input sizes.

What I am wondering is-- why this difference in strategies in sorting the primitive and non-primitives types?

The performance of the algorithm significantly depends on the input size-- not the data types. 
Invoking `compareTo()` instead of plain magnitude comparison on the primitives (>, <, ==) doesn't 
burn extra space in memory (and thus doesn't slow-down the absolute-time performance due to memory space) that would be considerable during run-time.

Why is `Arrays.sort()` methods using different sort strategies for the primitive data types, 
and for the complex data types?

TIA.

Comment: It's possible that the fact that object comparisons could end up being significantly more expensive than primitive comparisons might have played a role. I'm not familiar with either Timsort nor dual-pivot quicksort, so I can't say for sure. The javadoc does mention a number-of-comparisons advantage for Timsort, but seeing as there is no such thing for the other sorts, I can't really draw any conclusions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because sorting reference types is guaranteed to be [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), whereas sorting primitives does not need to be (so quicksort, a non-stable sorting algorithm, can be used; merge sort on the other hand is in fact stable). Also note that [quicksort is *generally* more optimal than mergesort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402/why-is-quicksort-better-than-mergesort) (see [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice) as well), which explains why it's taken advantage of when sorting primitives.

From [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

> This sort is guaranteed to be *stable*: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

Comment: +1. Much simpler explanation than the mess brewing in my head.