# Quicksort tends to O(n^2) in worst case for some input at least then why not merge sort and never use quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

Quicksort tends to O(n^2) in worst case for some input at least then why not always use merge sort and never use quicksort !!

Is there any practical use case where QuickSort is must ??

Comment: Now compare space requirements

Comment: and take into account that allocating space in real world is a really expensive operation

Comment: this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402/why-is-quicksort-better-than-mergesort

Comment: Beside all other concerns, the asymptotic worst-case behaviour of an algorithm is not the only criterion to judge its suitability for a specifitc purpose.

Comment: If you are sorting a lot of integers use Radix Sort O(N).